# udev rules daemon

Tags: udev, daemon, touch-screen

I have a touchscreen "EETI" and I am using the [official drivers](http://www.eeti.com/drivers_Linux.html).
The drivers work properly and the screen works fine. The problem is that the "driver" is a daemon that I have to start every time I boot the system.

To solve this, I have made a udev rule to detect a touch screen and launch the daemon but for some reason never gets to run the daemon.

Rule:

```
DRIVERS=="usb", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0eef", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7200", RUN+="/usr/bin/eGTouchD"
```

I have also tried to run a simple script but it does not work either.

Rule 2:

```
DRIVERS=="usb", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0eef", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7200", RUN+="/bin/sh /home/run.sh"
```

Script test

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "TEST!!!" >> /home/log.txt
```

device info:

```
looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0f.4/usb2/2-1':
    KERNELS=="2-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{configuration}=="eGalax Inc."
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="a0"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="25"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0eef"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="7200"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="1008"
...
```

I do not know what may be happening. Do you have any idea what may be happening or some other test that I can do?

System:

- Kernel 2.6.33

Thanks!

Regards!

Comment: Depending on versions, did you try explicitly reloading the rules, `udevadm control --reload`. You can also try `udevadm trigger` or running the daemon with debug `udevd --debug`.

Comment: It looks like you have to run the daemon as superuser. Can this be done from a udev rule?

Comment: Normally `udev` runs as root, and all the `RUN` commands are also run as root.  Your kernel is quite old; what version of Unix are you using?

Comment: You are right. I have found the problem. The program was starting but it did not get executed because it lacked a dependency of the program.
Thanks for the help.